# How to add an HTML attribute to the current URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, url, attributes

Sorry guys, noob jQuery question. This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="tag-buttons" href="#" data-id="&product_tag=273" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="button.default">
        Sistemas de asistencia
    </a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    url = window.location.href + attr('data-id');
      $(".tag-buttons").click(function(){
        $(".tag-buttons").attr("href", url);
      });
    });
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var url = window.location.href;
       $(".tag-buttons").click(function(){
         url+=$(this).data('id');
         // $(this).attr("href", url);
          window.location = url;
       });
     });
```

Comment: Thank you @Bellash! It worked with a mousedown() event. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your url, you forgot to tell where to take the data-id attribute.

Just replace:

```js
attr('data-id')
```

by

```js
$(".tag-buttons").attr('data-id')
```

Comment: I think `$(".tag-buttons").attr('data-id')` will return a set of matched elements consisting of all elements with class of `tag-buttons`. Unless there is only one element with the class of `tag-buttons`.

Comment: That's true. I was testing this on a separate document, but I want to use the data-id of the clicked element not all the data-id of the document.

Comment: Have you tried @Bellash answer? I think his answer will give you what you want.

Comment: When I tested it load the same page, I tried to open the link on a new tab, the old tab load the result I want with the data-id and the new one loads the same page without it. I solved this with a mousedown() event. It worked perfectly. Thank you.